# MacOS Swift App Restore Deleted Main Menu Item

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have deleted the default Edit menu from the main menu in main.storyboard but I would like to restore it. I have tried but I cannot find the answer to this, so help please.

Comment: You can add menus from the Library in your storyboard: Shift + Command + L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform these steps in Xcode to restore a lost Edit menu in a macOS storyboard:

1. Open the Library (+ button on the toolbar), while your storyboard with the menu is opened.
2. Enter 'edit' in the Library search box.
3. Drag-and-drop the Edit Menu Item from the Library to the correct position in the menu of your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks a million. You beat me to solving it on my own, where I created another project and copied the edit menu item from the storyboard on the new project to the storyboard on my old project